# Create BigQuery adwords transfer with my end user credential

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create google ads transfer from the python SDK but I am running into a curious issue.
To create a transfer in BigQuery, your GCP account should have the admin role of BigQuery and should also have the read access to the AdWords account. At first, we were creating the transfer manually, but now we have to implement it using pythons `google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer` package. The problem is this piece of code will run the production server which has a service account already present in it as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` so I cannot add my end-user account credentials that way. Also, we cannot provide the GoogleAds read-only access to a service account. Is there a way to create a BQ Transfer from the code using the end-user credentials or is there a way to create/generate a key file for an end-user account.

Note - I have tried using the key file that is generated using the application default gcloud command and its throwing `Service account info was not in the expected format, missing fields token_uri, client_email.` error.

Note - I came across the OAuth flow and just wondering if it can be done without that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the docummentation for authenticating the python application with a [service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#python).

-[Create a new service account](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#python) and configure the python client with the json file:

```
key_path = "path/to/service_account.json"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,)
```

Also, in case it helps, the way to authenticate your application with an [end-user account can be via OAuth](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user), for that, please follow the next steps:

-Authenticate and call the API as [described here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#authenticating_and_calling_the_api):

```
appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    "client_secrets.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
)
```

Finally, please refear to the best practices for user account, authentication and password management docummentation for correct implementation of your [credentials on the client side](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/12-best-practices-for-user-account).